# Render HTML in Drupal 8 error messages

Tags: theming, debugging

I'm working with Twig templates, and often see messages like this in the browser when I make a mistake:

```
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.</br></br><em class="placeholder">Twig\Error\SyntaxError</em>: Unclosed &quot;{&quot;. in <em class="placeholder">Twig\Lexer-&gt;lexExpression()</em> (line <em class="placeholder">153</em> of <em class="placeholder">themes/mytheme/templates/page.html.twig</em>). <pre class="backtrace">Twig\Lexer-&gt;lexBlock() (Line: 126)
Twig\Lexer-&gt;tokenize(Object) (Line: 705)

...etc.
```

Is there a way to automatically render the above HTML rather than having it output as a string? Thanks.

Comment: Are you creating that message, or is this a message the system or a contributed module is creating?

Comment: @Jaypan I'm editing Twig templates inside my custom theme. I believe this is a PHP message is emitted by Drupal core.

Comment: Ok, sorry I don’t have an answer then.

Comment: I say embrace the error as is then fix your mistake :)

Comment: This is fixed in Drupal 8.8.0, see https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2924860

Comment: Thanks @4k4, that looks like it.